# Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addComment/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hello I am trying to add comments to a page but when I press submit I get this error:
Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addComment/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['response']
```

Form on the page

```
        <form action="{% url 'CA:add_comment' id=climb.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for ="comment"></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id = "comment" rows = "5"placeholder="Add a comment"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value="Add Comment">
        </form>
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    response = models.CharField(default="Blank Comment", max_length=500)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,default= 1, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    climb = models.ForeignKey(Climb, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def addcomment(request, id):
    climb = Climb.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.response = request.POST["response"]
            data.username = request.user
            data.climb = climb
            data.save()
            return redirect('CA:cd', id=climb.id)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context={
        "form" : form

    }
    return render(request, "climbDetail.html",context=context)
```

urls.py

```
path('addComment/<int:id>/', views.addcomment, name='add_comment'),
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are not passing climb instance in context

Answer (score 0):

don't pass id like this `id=climb.id`
pass id like this `climb.id`
in your form

```
  context={
    "form" : form

}
```

so to access the id you should add this in in form action like this

```
<form action="{% url 'Ca:add_comment' form.id %}">
```

Comment: <form action="{% url 'CA:add_comment' climb.id %}" method="POST">

Comment: Ok I did that and I got the error: Reverse for 'add_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addComment/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: change this return redirect('CA:cd', id=climb.id) with this return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

Comment: It yields another:Reverse for 'add_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addComment/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
I might just have to put the comment form on a second page as I know that works

Comment: welp it turns out it wasn't working because in my comment form I had the area listed as comment when it should have been response. Thank you for for your help tho I really appreciated it. You made me look at my code step by step and thats why I was able to see the issue.